# How to get objectcontext from a control datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, frameworks, entity

I'm new in C# and Entity Framework. Is there a way to get back the `ObjectContext` from control datasource ?

I have three project , two for entity framework and the last one for window form application. The winform have two datagridview which each one from each EF project.

The issue are when I want to savechanges for datagridview A, I have to call `MyEF_A.SaveChanges()` and when I want to save datagridview B,  I have to call `MyEF_B.SaveChanges()`.

Is there a solution, so I can call `SaveChanges()` method base on `Form.ActiveControl` (datagridview A or datagridview B) tracing back from the `control.datasource` to `ObjectContext`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. The problem is that DataSource is of a type "object". Even though you could cast it to its original type, you never use ObjectContext itself as a binding object, so you would get just the collection.

I may be wrong though, please correct me someone if that's the case here.

Comment: the datagridview datasource from bindingsource dan bindingsource from List<TEntity>, I do successfull casting datagridview.datasource back to bindingsource but noluck casting back bindingsource back to List<TEntity>